# What is minimum period by which my cycles should be service?

Tags: maintenance, preventative-maintenance

I am using a Hercules MTB thriller,I drive a maximum of 75 km per week. When should I schedule periodic, quarterly full service for the bike?

Comment: Clarify this: do you travel on  pavement or dirt roads? Do you use high quality chain lube? What about weather conditions?

Comment: cycling on only proper state highways and city roads in India, rarely resorting to dirt roads and potholes (available in plenty in Indian road). Weather is humid and hot, very rarely rainy and very very rarely cold.

Comment: You should generally clean and oil the chain every 200-400km.  The chain should be replaced every 3000km or so (get a "chain stretch gauge" to check for the need to replace).  The rear cluster will need replacement every 8000km or so, the most heavily used front sprocket at about twice that long.  Wheel bearings (and bottom bracket if not sealed cartridge) should be repacked roughly every 20000km.  But a lot depends on conditions.  And more frequent service is needed if the bike is left in the rain a lot.

Answer (score 2):

On the bike you have, just keep the chain oiled and the brakes tight.
There is no point in bothering to service anything else, as regardless of what you do it will just drop off one fine day. In any case, single speed commuters don't need much maintenance.
The bike has really poor build quality.
Go to your bike shop to get stuff fixed when you have real problems.
As it is you'll have to throw away the bike in about 3 years(if you use it as much as you claim).
To everyone else reading the answer, the bike in question is [this](http://www.junglee.com/Hercules-Thriller-Black-Arabian-gold/dp/B0087CKVJS). A $75(USD) commuter BSO.